# Selected dropdown value is missing in email after completing a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, email

I'm currently creating a web form that differs based on a first selection in a dropdown. This dropdown is initially the only field that is displayed. Once the user selected for example the first value, then the following code is creating all the form fields:

```
   if(sel_value==1)   
   {
   $("div#form1").slideDown('slow');

    $("div#form1").append(
    $("#form_submit").append(
    $("<div/>",{id:'head'}).append(
    $("<h3/>").text("RESERVATIEFORMULIER")),
    $("<input/>", {type:'text', placeholder:'Naam', name:'Naam'}),
    $("<br/>"),
    $("<input/>", {type:'text', placeholder:'E-mail', name:'E-mailadres'}),
    $("<br/>"),
    $('<select> id:"voorstelling",placeholder: "voorstelling", name: "voorstelling"').append(
    $('<option value ="Vrijdag 7 november 2014">Vrijdag 7 november</option><option value ="Zaterdag 8 november 2014">Zaterdag 8 november</option></select>')),
    $("<br/>"),
    $("<br/>"),
    $("<select/>",{id:'voorkeur', placeholder: 'voorkeur', name: 'Voorkeur'}).append(
    $("<option value/>").text("Geen plaatsvoorkeur"),
    $("<option value/>").text("Tribune"),
    $("<option value/>").text("Zo dicht mogelijk bij podium")),
    $("<br/>"),
    $("<textarea/>", {placeholder:'Opmerkingen', type:'text', name:'Opmerkingen'}),
    $("<br/>"),
    $("<input/>", {type:'hidden', name:'recipient', value:'info@toneelgroep-prutske.be'}),
    $("<hr/>"),
    $("<input/>", {type:'hidden', name:'subject', value:'Reservatie via webformulier'}),
    $("<br/>"),
    $("<hr/>"),
    $("<hr/>")
                 ))
    }
```

After the user has clicked on a submit button, the values are sent to the webmaster. This is working fine, except for the 2 selected picklist values in the form (id= voorkeur & voorstelling). These parameters are blank in the email.
The email is composed via php and the parameters are filled via the following code:

```
$voorstelling = $_POST['voorstelling'];
$voorkeur = $_POST['voorrkeur'];
```

I don't see why it's not sending the selected values via email. As you can see, I tried 2 different ways to create the picklists in the form, but using the 1 way or the other doesn't make a difference.

Can anyone help me to get the values sent via email as well? The input fields are sent correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you creating static html with JavaScript?

Comment: I would like to show a different form based on a first selection. That's why I'm running a function in javascript to check which option was selected.

Answer (score 0):

Misspelling:

`$voorkeur = $_POST['voorrkeur'];`

should be:

`$voorkeur = $_POST['voorkeur'];`

Comment: Thanks guys for your suggestions. However, I updated my code accordingly and it's still not sending me the selected picklist values :(

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your JS

```
$('<select> id:"voorstelling",placeholder: "voorstelling", name: "voorstelling"')
```

Should probably be

```
$('<select>', {id:"voorstelling",placeholder: "voorstelling", name: "voorstelling"})
```

I would HIGHLY suggest using a console (every browser has one, hit F12 by default) and inspecting the element AFTER the page has fully rendered. Helps you find problems like this.